# add what contains in element along with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to add the content of each `span` along with the value in the `title` attribute.

```
<div id="group-wrap" class="group">
    <span class="lbracket" title="&f">(</span>
    <span class="grouptitle" title="&f"> Group </span>
    <span class="rbracket" title="&f">) </span>
    <span class="username" title="&f"> Username </span>
    <span class="col" title="&f">:</span>
    <span class="text" title="&f"> Helo There! </span>
</div>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
var str = [];
    $('#group-wrap span').each(function(){
        str.push($(this).attr('title'));
    });
    alert(str.join(''));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B9QeK/3/

The output is `&f&f&f&f&f` (the value of each title attribute), but the expected output has the value, plus the content that is in the span. The value of the attribute should be appended before the content.

```
&f(&fGroup&f)&fUsername: &f text
```

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for

```
str.push( this.getAttribute('title'), this.textContent || this.text );
```

As for performance reasons, you should not re-create a jQuery object for every single iteration. Even better, don't use jQuery at all to receive those values.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9QeK/8/)

And by the way, you can make usage of jQuerys `.map()` to do it a bit more elegant:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var str = $('#group-wrap span').map(function(){
        return this.getAttribute('title') + this.textContent || this.text;
    }).get();

    alert(str.join(''));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9QeK/9/)

Reference: [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(function($){
    var str = [];
    $('#group-wrap span').each(function(){
        str.push($(this).attr('title') + $(this).text());
    });
    alert(str.join(''));
});
```

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9QeK/7/)**

`text`:

> Description: Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

**[docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to get the text content of each `span`:

```
var str = [];
    $('#group-wrap span').each(function(){
        //Push value of title attribute and text content into array:
        str.push($(this).attr('title') + $(this).text());
    });
    alert(str.join(''));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
str.push($(this).attr('title'));
```

Should look like:

```
str.push($(this).attr('title') + $(this).text());
```

Although, this is making two identical calls `$(this)`, so you might consider caching:

```
var $this = $(this)
str.push($this.attr('title') + $this.text());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "";
    $('#group-wrap span').each(function(){
        str+=$(this).attr('title')+$(this).text();
    });
    alert(str);
});
```